# kendo grid filter operator

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a datasource I use for a grid.
The grid has server filtering, which works fine. 
The issue is-Filter is giving the results based on contains operator only(irrespective of what I have selected) 
how to get the filter operator from filter operator options.

Please help me

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("ViewDataGrid")

```
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Title(" ID").Width(150);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Title(" Name").Width(150);

        })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: auto; width: 2200px" })
    .Filterable(i => i.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu | GridFilterMode.Row))
    .Sortable(s => s.AllowUnsort(false).SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
    .Selectable(selecting => selecting.Enabled(true))                               
    .Pageable(r => r.PreviousNext(true).PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100 }))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Events(e => e.Change("call"))
        ))
function call(e) {

    if (e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters != null) {
        if (e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].value == "") {                     
            $('#ViewDataGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.filter({});
        }
        else {
            var filterlength = e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters.length;
            $filter = new Array();
            if (e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].field == "Id")
            $filter.push({ field: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].field, operator: "eq", value: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].value });
            else
            $filter.push({ field: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].field, operator: "contains", value: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].value });
            $("#ViewDataGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter($filter);

        }
    }
}
```

#### Model.CS

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

#### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<GridData> dataList = new List<GridData>(); 
    GridData data1 = new GridData();
    data1.Id = 9191919;
    data1.Name = "XYZ";           
    dataList.Add(data1);
    return View(dataList);           
}
```

Comment: We need more information and also a sample of your code.. Are you using a server side filter? entityframework?

Comment: I have attached the code. Please give me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

you might enable only the 'Is equal to' filter for the ID field

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("ViewDataGrid")

    .Columns(columns =>
    {
            columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Title(" ID").Width(150).Filterable(f => f.Operators(op => op.ForNumber(opn => opn.Clear().IsEqualTo("Is equal to") )));
            columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Title(" Name").Width(150);
        })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: auto; width: 300px" })
    .Filterable(i => i.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu | GridFilterMode.Row))
    .Sortable(s => s.AllowUnsort(false).SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
    .Selectable(selecting => selecting.Enabled(true))
    .Pageable(r => r.PreviousNext(true).PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100 }))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(false)
    ))
```